# Добавить имя к IP адресу

Tags: ping, провайдер, google-search

При сканирование некоторых `IP`, заметил, что у некоторых есть «имя». Например, у гугла - `95-30-216-45.broadband.corbina.ru`. Что это за «имя» и как этого добиться у себя на сервере?

> ```
> PING google.com (95.30.216.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from 95-30-216-45.broadband.corbina.ru (95.30.216.45): icmp_seq=1 ttl=5
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данное «имя» (являющееся доменным) утилита `ping` получает отдельным запросом к сервисам [Reverse Lookup DNS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_DNS). Данные сервисы позволяют узнать доменное имя по IP-адресу (если оно существует). Причём это не обязательно имя сайта; DNS позволяет присваивать имена узлам вне зависимости от их назначения.

---

Указанный IP-адрес принадлежит Корбине Телеком. Судя по тому, что этот адрес работает и у меня, могу предположить, что Корбина размещает у себя партнёрское зеркало Google для обеспечения быстрого доступа.

Возможно, вы являетесь клиентом этого оператора связи, и он автоматически направляет вас на собственное зеркало.